# Rcpp sourceCpp compiler settings

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using Rcpp to speed up a function that gets called repeatedly in R (3.4, Windows7) and I was hoping to change the compiler settings.

When I call:
`sourceCpp("scoreseq1.1.cc", verbose=TRUE)`

Part of the output reads:

> C:/RBuildTools/3.4/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include"      -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c scoreseq1.1.cc -o scoreseq1.1.o

I would like to change `-mtune` to `haswell`, and `-O2` to `-O3` in search of some performance improvements.

Is there a way to do that through the `sourceCpp` or `cppFunction`, do I need a special header in my.cc file, or do I need to I need to modify some file on my system (and if so, what file?!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't (easily), and in general not from a function.

These settings are "fixed" from when R itself is built. You can edit the file -- but you will have to so each time R is rebuilt / reinstalled.

On my box the file is `$(R RHOME)/etc/Makeconf`.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I played with the settings and found that they made no difference (except in a few cases where the code ran marginally slower). Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. And kudos to you for realizing these settings may not matter on short/small snippets.  But it is always worth trying to measure, and that that you did.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone has a similar problem. You can do this in your C++ source. The following overrides command-line compiler settings:

```
void
__attribute__((optimize("-O3"),target("tune=haswell")))
foo() 
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

For reference take a look at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.